# ajax to submit the form information

Tags: php, jquery

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name=qty" />
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="formSubmit(event)" />
</form>
```

now, i using ajax to submit the information to `http://example.com/test.php`. how to access the `inputname`,`email`,`phone`,`message` value in test.php, i konw, if don't use ajax, i can used $_POST['email']..to access the passed value.

if i also want to use  $_POST['email'].how do i do? after instructed by someone, i did the following, but in the test.php. it doesn't access the vaule, what's wrong with it?

```
var dataString =  '&name=' + jQuery('input[name=name]').val() +                 
                         '&email=' + jQuery('input[name=email]').val() +
                         '&qty=' + jQuery('input[name=qty]').val() +
                         '&message=' + jQuery('textarea[name=message]').val() +
       jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.example.com/test.php",
            data: dataString,
```

then in test.php i using.  $_POST['email'],$_POST['qty']...it doesn't work.

the last code: i added class="ajax-submit" to the

```
jQuery('form.ajax-submit').submit(function(e) {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($this.find('input[name="email"]').val() == '' || $this.find('input[name="qty"]').val() == ''|| $this.find('input[name="message"]').val()=='')) {
    alert("please fill out the required fields");
    return false;
}

    jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://example.com/test.php",
         data: $this.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function() {
                alert('There was an error submitting the form');
            } 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't construct the query string by hand. What you have now doesn't escape the values, which makes it easy to break.

Instead, just let jQuery serialize the form for you:

```
$('form.ajax-submit').submit(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: $this.attr('action') || window.location,
        type: $this.attr('method') || 'post',
        data: $this.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    })
});
```

This code makes all forms with the class `ajax-submit` submit via AJAX.

To fix what you have now, just change your `data` key's value:

```
var $form = $('#your_form');

if ($form.find('input[name="email"]').val() == '' || $form.find('input[name="name"]').val() == '') {
    return false;
}

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/test.php",
    data: $form.serialize(),
    ...
```

Comment: i am sorry, i don't follow your code well, http://www.example.com/test.php where to put the url in your code? what this form.ajax-submit' meaning?

Comment: @stackoverflow002: `http://www.example.com/test.php` is pulled from the form's `action` attribute. `form.ajax-submit` selects all forms that have a class of `ajax-submit`. I tried to make it as readable as possible, but if you have trouble with it I suggest you take a look at a jQuery tutorial. It's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @stackoverflow002: See my edit for how to fix your current code.

Comment: i got it.it's ok. but when i click the submit button, i will receive two emails.(test.php send the data as an email to my email box)

Comment: @stackoverflow002: Make sure that you don't have something else sending another AJAX request.

Comment: if the email and qty input are empty, i will prevent the form submit. how do i do? where to add jQuery('input[name=email]').val()=='' and jQuery('input[name=name]').val() =='' code in the submit functioin –

Comment: when i add  alert("please fill out the required fields"); before the  return false; although i filled out the  required fields,it still show the tips? why

Comment: the last question, many thanks. i put the whole code in my question,now, when i add if ($this.find('input[name="email"]').val() == '' || $this.find('input[name="qty"]').val() == ''|| $this.find('input[name="message"]').val()=='')) {
    alert("please fill out the required fields");
    return false;
} the code doesn't work.

Comment: @stackoverflow002: You have an extra `)` after `.val()=='')`.

Comment: now, i want to extend the success function, i want to do a modal to it, when i test with this code. success: function() {
             success();            
            alert("test");
        },why it not run the alert?

Answer (score 1):

just use it this way:

```
jQuery('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/test.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        },
        error:function(){
          alert('error');
        }
});
```

Comment: i using  $_POST['email'] in test.php to access the passed information,am i right?

Comment: yes. i put '?name='  in submit function, $_POST['name'] in test.php

Comment: in the `test.php` are you echoing `$_POST['email']` ?

Comment: i got it.it's ok. but when i click the submit button, i will receive two emails.(test.php send the data as an email to my email box)

Comment: if the email and qty input are empty, i will prevent the form submit. how do i do? where to add jQuery('input[name=email]').val()=='' and jQuery('input[name=name]').val() =='' in the submit functioin

Comment: just after form submit function then return false if inputs are blank

Comment: now, i want to extend the success function, i want to write a pop function which can pop up a window to it, when i test with this code. success: function() { success(); alert("test"); },why it not run the alert?

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery plugin that does the work:
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

It simply does all the AJAX work for you as you were simply submitting the form in the former way.